# making a jsonp call from within PHP script

Tags: php, json

I am not sure if this is even possible since I m new to PHP. I have a URL (for instance: http://www.mysite.com/data/response/) which gives me some cookie data as json respose ( {"cookie_name":"value","ttl":60} ). I have a php script that thows some output based on a cookie value. So, right on top of this php script I need to make a call to the above url, get the json response/interpret it and set a cookie based on the response. Can someone please help me with this?

Many thanks in advance.
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/data/response/';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($result, true);

set_cookie('cookie_name', $json['value'], time() + ((int) $json['ttl']));
```

As *cwallenpoole* mentioned in comments below, make sure that `allow_url_fopen` runtime configuration variable is set to TRUE (it is by default). If not - use `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)`, but it may be restricted by safe mode I think :)

`json_decode` function has been introduced in PHP 5.2.0. If you have PHP >= 5.2 and `json_decode` is not available, please check if JSON extension is enabled (`extension=json.so` in your php.ini) and if you PHP was combiled with `--disable-json` flag.

If you use pre-5.2 PHP then you can use following code (introduced by Anonymous user on PHP.net):

```
if ( !function_exists('json_decode') ){
function json_decode($json)
{
$comment = false;
$out = '$x=';

for ($i=0; $i<strlen($json); $i++)
{
    if (!$comment)
    {
        if (($json[$i] == '{') || ($json[$i] == '['))       $out .= ' array(';
        else if (($json[$i] == '}') || ($json[$i] == ']'))   $out .= ')';
        else if ($json[$i] == ':')    $out .= '=>';
        else                         $out .= $json[$i];          
    }
    else $out .= $json[$i];
    if ($json[$i] == '"' && $json[($i-1)]!="\\")    $comment = !$comment;
}
eval($out . ';');
return $x;
}
}
```

---

If `allow_url_fopen` is set to 0 and you cannot change it by `ini_set` or by setting it in your php.ini file, that you can stick to cURL (if cURL extension is enabled :)):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER_HEADER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The rest code should work as in first example. Hope it helps!

Comment: You should mention that this only works if `allow_url_fopen` is set to `1` (which by default is, but can be disabled).

Comment: If you want an associative array from `json_decode`, you need to pass the second parameter as TRUE.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: you are right, thanks! @Felix Kling: thank you for your update too.

Comment: Thanks a ton WASD42 :) unfortunately in my system even "file_get_contents" is somehow disabled and even worse! I have no access to the PHP config!

Comment: @LShetty: You are welcome! Try using `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1)` before calling `file_get_contents()` then.

Comment: @WASD42: So, replace "$result = file_get_contents($url);
" with the 3rd code block in your example above?

Comment: alright, that gave me some hope! code now gets executed fine, however there is a new problem. When I use your code it prints {"cookie_name":"improper","ttl":60} but the actual value is something else. I say this because when I drop the url into the browser address bar I get a different value which is the correct value. Why is this? [Thanks - L]

Comment: @WASD42 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1214/discussion-between-lshetty-and-wasd42)